# How do I set a fixed marker size in a seaborn/matplotlib legend?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am attempting to set a fixed marker size for the legend on a seaborn pointplot with the following code:

```
        ax = sns.pointplot(x="Rank", y="Yld_Vol_Dr", data=df, markers="", join=True, ci=None, color="darkslategrey", scale=0.5)
        ax = sns.pointplot(x="Rank", y="Yld_Vol_Dr", data=df, hue="Rank", palette=rankpalette, errwidth=4, saturation=1)
        leg = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.05), loc='upper left', title="Rank")
        for handle in leg.legendHandles:
            handle.set_sizes([6.0])
```

This works for all but the first marker which remains larger than the others:

[image]

How do I fix this so all markers are fixed at the same size?